# How can I load XML files with different schema into database using XML Source component?

Tags: c#, xml, ssis, xsd

I have a folder that contains many XML files that have different XML schemas. The XML source Component identified in all these files 4 tables, 3 from it are of identical form but it is one table that has a number of columns which varies depending on the XML file. so when I work with XML source  Component I have a problem with the xsd  file. The XML source component does not work without the right xsd file.

Is there a way to generate xsd file dynamically for each xml file because I work with a ForEach loop or another method to load XML files without generating their xsd.

If the answer includes script component, I am using c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSD file should include the superset of all attributes.  The XML source component then wont care if some attributes do not appear in a particular XML file - it will pass nulls for those values.